# insert quotation marks around all words in string in python

Tags: python

I have a string in a column that looks likes this

```
x = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': 
                       [({"Name":"any","all":[{"First":"True","Second":False},{"Last":True,"Second":False}],"Entry":0})]}).applymap(str)
```

some random fields are not wrapped in quotation marks, but they should be. I tried stripping all quotes and then reinserting quotes around all words within the string with the following, but its not quite working correctly - as shown below

```
x['a'][0].strip(' \" ')

' '.join('"{}"'.format(w) for w in x['a'][0].split(' '))
```

which gives the following output

```
"{'Name':" "'any'," "'all':" "[{'First':" "'True'," "'Second':" "False}," "{'Last':" "True," "'Second':" "False}]," "'Entry':" "0}"
```

the expected output would be this

```
{"Name":"any","all":[{"First":"True","Second":"False"},{"Last":"True","Second":"False"}],"Entry":"0"}
```

any advice would be great. thanks so much!

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
import json

x = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': 
                       [({"Name":"any","all":[{"First":"True","Second":False},{"Last":True,"Second":False}],"Entry":0})]})

replacer = re.compile("(\w+)")
x['a'] = replacer.sub(r'"\1"', json.dumps(x['a'][0]).replace('"', ''))
```

---

**Explanation**
See the Python [regex docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more info...
`(\w+)` : `()` matches whatever is in the parentheses and denotes a capturing group. `\w` matches unicode word characters. `+` with one or more occurrences.

The `sub` method has the signature `Pattern.sub(repl, string, count=0)`. This returns the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.
`"\1"` is the first captured group in the regex expression with double quotation marks.

We need to use JSON since we want to serialise the now Pandas object into a JSON string. This leads to the expected behavior, instead of casting to a string in pandas which adds the `'` you experienced.
The `.replace('"', '')` gets rid of the occurrences of double quotes such that the regex sub method doesn't add additional ones.

Comment: thanks for the response! I appreciate it alot. and it works so thank you! can you explain how perhaps? Also interesting - i tried applying it to another set of data and it inserted backslashes in the whitespace for some reason. is that to be expected?

Comment: No problem. I have added the explanation as an edit. Can you reply with a minimal example of this happening with some explanation please.

Comment: the issue can be replicated if you add the .applymap(str) when creating the df

Answer (score 2):

Trying to insert quotation marks via regular expressions has a number of disadvantages:

1. It disregards the fact that the given string is machine-readable
2. It will fail (or at least produce strange results) as soon as any key or value contains something that's not matched by `\w`, e.g., `"First-one"` instead of "First"
3. Using regular expressions is generally not very fast

If these concerns are irrelevant for your task, you can certainly do it that way – but it's quite hacky and not guaranteed to work all the time, so here's a cleaner approach.

The thing is that

```py
s = """{"Name":"any","all":[{"First":"True","Second":False},{"Last":True,"Second":False}],"Entry":0}"""
```

is a structured string – from the looks of it, it's a stringified Python `dict` that can be turned back into a proper data structure with `eval()`:

```py
d = eval(s)
```

(I wonder where you got that string though? If it was a Python `dict` in the first place, turning it into a string first and trying to "fix" it by messing with it later on is generally not a good idea.)

The values that miss quotation marks are *not* "random" values, but a `bool` and an `int`, respectively, i.e., they are missing quotation marks because they *aren't strings*. However, they can be stringified by calling `str()` on each of them individually. So, a clean way to turn those values into strings is something like the following, which might look a bit different depending on how the complete data set is structured:

```py
for i,elem in enumerate(d['all']):
    for k,v in elem.items():
        d['all'][i][k] = str(v)
        
d['Entry'] = str(d['Entry'])
```

Result:

```py
{'Name': 'any', 'all': [{'First': 'True', 'Second': 'False'}, {'Last': 'True', 'Second': 'False'}], 'Entry': '0'}
```

Comment: thats really interesting thanks so much. I just ran it on a single string and it works exactly as expected so that's great. Also you are right the data is not a python dict its been outputted from another program and may have lost some formatting along the way. Can i ask how you would do this for an entire column?  
e.g. with this - 
x = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': 
                       [({"Name":"any","all":[{"First":"True","Second":False},{"Last":True,"Second":False}],"Entry":0}),
                       ({"Gender":"any","all":[{"Male":"True","Female":True}],"Entry":1})]})

Comment: Answered my own question 
`for ind in x.index:
    x['a'][ind]['Entry'] = str(x['a'][ind]['Entry'])
    for i,elem in enumerate(x['a'][ind]['all']):
        for k,v in elem.items():
            x['a'][ind]['all'][i][k] = str(v)`